# How could this be written better/simpler?

Tags: javascript

I'm practising my JavaScript skills a came up with an idea of a button that changes through an array of colours every time I click it.

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const colours = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'];
let cycle = 1;
button.style.backgroundColor = colours[0];
button.addEventListener('click', e => {

    button.style.backgroundColor = colours[cycle];
    cycle++;
    if (cycle == 4) {
        cycle = 0;
    };
});
```

Comment: The `if` could be `cycle %= 4;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is pretty nice and clear, I can just show you how to do it without using cycle variable and use only the colours array and array functions to get the current position and increment it.
I'm using the remainer of division by colours array lenght to stay in array size

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const colours = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'];
button.style.backgroundColor = colours[0]
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    button.style.backgroundColor = colours[(colours.indexOf(button.style.backgroundColor)+1)%colours.length];
});
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought mine should of looked something like this

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of post-incrementation and modulo operator. Also, in the event callback, you can use `e.target` instead of `button` variable directly:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const colours = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'];
let cycle = 1;
button.style.backgroundColor = colours[0];
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = colours[cycle++ % colours.length];
});
```

```html
<button>M</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a different and more functional programming approach - you could create a `cycleColours` function, which uses a closure and returns a function to cycle over the colours, which returns the next in the array each time it is called.

This way, you can re-use this function elsewhere, and abstracts the logic from the click handler against the `button`.

```js
const cycleColours = (coloursArray = []) => {
  const colours = coloursArray;
  let index = 0;

  const incrementIndex = () => {
    index++;
    if (index >= colours.length) index = 0;
  };

  return () => {
    const colour = colours[index];
    incrementIndex();
    return colour;
  };
};

const coloursButtonOne = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
const getButtonOneColour = cycleColours(coloursButtonOne);

const coloursButtonTwo = ['yellow', 'pink', 'purple', 'white']
const getButtonTwoColour = cycleColours(coloursButtonTwo);

const buttonOne = document.querySelector('button#one');
const buttonTwo = document.querySelector('button#two');

buttonOne.style.backgroundColor = getButtonOneColour();
buttonTwo.style.backgroundColor = getButtonTwoColour();

buttonOne.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = getButtonOneColour();
});

buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = getButtonTwoColour();
});
```

```html
<button id="one">Click Me!</button>
<button id="two">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about what i'd do to create another button. thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are my five cent:

My strategy is

1. Style as much as you can with CSS. Try to prevent inline styles or setting style with JavaScript.
2. Don't directly add EventListeners to an element. Add EventListeners to the document instead. Use the event bubbling.
3. Encapsulate variables names (that's what the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is for)

```js
// IIFE to encapsulate variable names
(function(w, d) {
  const className = 'color-cycle';
  const selector = `.${className}`;
  const cycles = 4

  // add EventListener to document not the element
  d.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // check the target of the event, if it is inside the button
    const button = e.target.closest(selector);
    if (button) {
      // Use `data-` attribute to store cycle
      button.dataset.cycle = (parseInt(button.dataset.cycle || 0) + 1) % cycles
    }
  });
}(window, document));

// For demonstration purposes
(function(d) {
  const selector = `#add-button`;
  const className = 'color-cycle';

  d.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const button = e.target.closest(selector);
    if (button) {
      const newButton = d.createElement('button');
      newButton.classList.add(className);
      newButton.textContent = 'Button'
      d.body.appendChild(newButton);
      d.body.appendChild(d.createTextNode("\n"))
    }
  })
}(document));
```

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 9px;
}

button.color-cycle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}
button.color-cycle,
button.color-cycle[data-cycle="0"] {
  background-color: red;
}

button.color-cycle[data-cycle="1"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

button.color-cycle[data-cycle="2"] {
  background-color: green;
}

button.color-cycle[data-cycle="3"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button id="add-button">Add Button</button><br><br>

<button class="color-cycle">Button 1</button>
<button class="color-cycle">Button 2</button>
<button class="color-cycle">Button 3</button>
<button class="color-cycle">Button 4</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've not seen the [data-cycle] before, will definately look into it

Comment: The `cycle` is a term I invented. You could have set anything at this point

Comment: @See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

Comment: @See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Comment: @See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors